# Python: Test Mixpanel locally > SSL error

Tags: python, django, mixpanel

I am trying to test Mixpanel locally but always run into this SSL error:

```
MixpanelException at /register/D66Ly6ngyQ3I5boSQc9lBlrwiC2m3qbFAc5uMy3mstsZZcpFGXbi9TMUJf9hsGyh/

    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)>
```

Now I found [here](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-ruby/issues/83#issuecomment-150086948) an explanation how to solve this with Ruby:

```
# config/initializers/mixpanel.rb
if Rails.env.development? 
  # silence local SSL errors
  Mixpanel.config_http do |http|
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  end
end
```

However, I can't find any solution for Python. Do you have any ideas how to test Mixpanel locally?

Comment: what is your local machine running on? osx? windows? linux?

Comment: It is running on osx

Comment: Are you able to fetch any SSL content at all using `urllib`? Better way to test would be to `pip install requests` and then in a python shell try `import requests; requests.get('https://api.mixpanel.com/track')` which should give a mixpanel error (rather than a SSL certificate error).

Comment: That gave me a <Response [200]>. Does it mean there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Not sure how to help then sorry, I'm assuming you're using mixpanel-python? You might want to try to send a request manually like in the `Consumer.write_request()` [method](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-python/blob/master/mixpanel/__init__.py#L357). So try: `request = urllib.request.Request(request_url, encoded_data)` and then `response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)`. (you'll have to import urllib and construct an encoded_data object, not important what's in there). If you get a response.status of 200 then I really don't know why it's not working in your code.

Comment: By the way, does the same error happen when you just use Mixpanel in the command-line as shown in the documentation? `mp = Mixpanel(YOUR_TOKEN)` and then `mp.track(DISTINCT_ID, 'button clicked', {'color' : 'blue', 'size': 'large'})` also gives the SSL error?

Comment: What actually solved it was that comment here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10779#issuecomment-313514199

I don't really understand what was wrong or what I changed that it works now. But if you know what that command did, I would be very interested to understand it.